# Is current row value in other column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Im trying to determine if a user is a manager by determining if their Id `userProfiles.UserProfilesId` is anywhere in the field `UserProfiles.ManagerId`. My current sql statment says id is not valid. Is there any subquery I could create to determine this information?

```
SELECT
      IsNull(PersonalTimeRemaining, 0) as PTO,
      UserProfiles.UserProfileId as id,
      us.Email,
      us.LastName + ', ' + us.FirstName,
      managers.Email as 'manager',
      case when PersonalTimeRemaining is null then 'hourly' else 'salary' end as salaryType,
      case when 
        EXISTS(SELECT * from UserProfiles where id = UserProfiles.UserProfileId)
      then 'User' else 'Manager' end as salaryType
  FROM UserProfiles
  inner join Users as us on us.UserId = UserProfiles.UserProfileId
  inner join Users as managers on managers.UserId = UserProfiles.ManagerId
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You already heve the ID from UserProfiles why you need a subquery?

Comment: seems like you have a typo: `where id = UserProfiles.UserProfileId`, shouldn't that be `ManagerId = UserProfiles.UserProfileId`?

Comment: As an aside, since you are using inner joins, this query will only return users who are both regular users and managers.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example... in this case I'm using table aliases (T and T2) and a correlated sub-query to query the same table's managerID's.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE (UserProfileID int, ManagerID int)
INSERT INTO @test VALUES (1, 4), (2, 4), (3, 4), (4, 5)

SELECT UserProfileID
      ,CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT T2.ManagerID
                           FROM @test T2
                          WHERE T2.ManagerID = T.UserProfileID
                        )
             THEN 'Manager'
             ELSE 'User'
       END AS salaryType

  FROM @test T
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to the subquery or to join the table twice, it's simply:

```
SELECT COLUMN ..
       CASE WHEN UP.UserProfileId IS NULL THEN 'Manager' ELSE 'User' END AS SalaryType
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN UserProfiles UP ON 
     U.UserId = UP.UserProfileId
```

Here is a simple example to understand it well:

```
CREATE TABLE Users (
    UserId INT
    -- Other columns
    );
CREATE TABLE UserProfiles (
    UserProfileId INT
    -- Other columns
    );

INSERT INTO Users VALUES
(1), (2);
INSERT INTO UserProfiles VALUES
(2);

SELECT U.UserId,
       CASE WHEN UP.UserProfileId IS NULL THEN 'Manager' ELSE 'User' END AS SalaryType
FROM Users U LEFT JOIN UserProfiles UP ON U.UserId = UP.UserProfileId;
```